# remove repeated words from String Array

Tags: java, arrays, text

Good Morning

I write a function that calculates for me the frequency of a term:

```
public static int tfCalculator(String[] totalterms, String termToCheck) {
    int count = 0;  //to count the overall occurrence of the term termToCheck
    for (String s : totalterms) {
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(termToCheck)) {
            count++; 
        }
    } 
    return count;
}
```

and after that I use it on the code below to calculate every word from a `String[] words`

```
for(String word:words){
    int freq = tfCalculator(words, word);

    System.out.println(word + "|" + freq);
    mm+=word + "|" + freq+"\n";
}
```

well the problem that I have is that the words repeat here is for example the result:

- cytoskeletal|2
- network|1
- enable|1
- equal|1
- spindle|1
- cytoskeletal|2
- ...
- ...

so can someone help me to remove the repeated word and get as result like that:

- cytoskeletal|2
- network|1
- enable|1
- equal|1
- spindle|1
- ...
- ...

Thank you very much!

Comment: put the array in a `Set` and the duplicates are gone

Comment: @KevinEsche not good to calculate the frequency though. I'd use a `Map<Integer, String>` to map the words to their frequencies. Then again, there's quite a few better ways to calculate the frequency itself, but that's another story.

Comment: Can you please post the full program?

Comment: Side note on code quality: some of the names of your variables (like mm) or methods ... are pretty bad. If you give your method a name that says what it really does; things become much clearer. Like: `int countOccurancesOfTerm(String term, String[] stringsToCheck)` or something alike.

Comment: @Mena thank you for the answer can you explain how i'd work with `Map<Integer, String>`, or anathor way to calculate the Term frequency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here you want to print the frequency of each string in the array totalterms . I think using Map is a easier solution as in the single traversal of the array it will store the frequency of all the strings Check the following implementation.

```
public static void printFrequency(String[] totalterms)
{
    Map frequencyMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String string : totalterms) {
        if(frequencyMap.containsKey(string))
        {
            Integer count = (Integer)frequencyMap.get(string);
            frequencyMap.put(string, count+1);
        }
        else
        {
            frequencyMap.put(string, 1);
        }
    }

    Set <Entry<String, Integer>> elements= frequencyMap.entrySet();

    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : elements) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"|"+entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Saurav this work well for me i really appreciate it

Comment: This is extremely verbose and unnecessary... Better check some of the other solutions @HaKiM's

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 solution

```
words = Arrays.stream(words).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
```

the `distinct` method removes duplicates. `words` is replaced with a new array without duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and that should take care of the duplicates issue:

```
words = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(words)).toArray(new String[0]);
```

This will take your array, convert it to a `List`, feed that to the constructor of `HashSet<String>`, and then convert it back to an array for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array, then you can just count equal adjacent elements:

```
Arrays.sort(totalterms);
int i = 0;
while (i < totalterms.length) {
  int start = i;
  while (i < totalterms.length && totalterms[i].equals(totalterms[start])) {
    ++i;
  }
  System.out.println(totalterms[start] + "|" + (i - start));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in two line :

```
String s = "cytoskeletal|2 - network|1 - enable|1 - equal|1 - spindle|1 - cytoskeletal|2";
System.out.println(new LinkedHashSet(Arrays.asList(s.split("-"))).toString().replaceAll("(^\[|\]$)", "").replace(", ", "- "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, you just need keep track of which words were encountered already. For that you can keep a running set:

```
Set<String> prevWords = new HashSet<>();
for(String word:words){
    // proceed if word is new to the set, otherwise skip
    if (prevWords.add(word)) {
        int freq = tfCalculator(words, word);

        System.out.println(word + "|" + freq);
        mm+=word + "|" + freq+"\n";
    }
}
```